# Unable to serialize sub-classes of my parent object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, entity

I'm building a service to take data from SQL and wrap it up into entity objects and then build these into "Payload" to be serizlied and sent over to another service. I'm going to have 3 different types of Payloads. I will have a Request object which will contain a Header object and a RequestPayload object, the RequestPayload contains a list of Payload objects, these Payload objects contain my entities. My 3 types of Payloads will each contain some common attributes, but also some specific to their type, so I've created a "Payload" object which has XmlAttributes for each of the common attributes between all Payload types. I then have my 3 other payloads each containing their specific attributes, but they all inherit Payload. I want to avoid having to create different RequestPayload types just to hold my different Payload objects, I'd like to create a single RequestPayload object and be able to serizlie it no matter what type of Payload it contains. This is how I've set it up, but I'm getting a run-time error when trying to serialize.

Request:

```
public class Request
{
    [XmlElement]
    public RequestHeader RequestHeader { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public RequestPayload RequestPayload { get; set; }
}
```

RequestPayload:

```
public class RequestPayload
{
    // used to be lossincurredpayload
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Payload> BOM_Request { get; set; }
}
```

Payload:

```
public class Payload
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int path { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int sequenceNum { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string requestSentDate { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string validationType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int transactionId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string decisionType { get; set; }

}
```

LossIncurredPayload (one of my specific payload types):

```
public class LossIncurredPayload : Payload
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<LossIncurred> BOM_Policy { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my code that is doing the serialization. I am getting get following error when the Serialize() method is called:
`"The type LossIncurredPayload was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."`

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(LossIncurredPayload))]
public string SerializeRequestToXml(Request request)
{
    // Instantiate the serializer
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    String xmlRequest;

    XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, request, xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue);

    xmlRequest = stringWriter.ToString();

    xmlRequest = xmlRequest.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8");

    // Print request for testing
    Console.WriteLine("Request: " + xmlRequest);

    return xmlRequest;
}
```

Any ideas how I might be able to get this to work? The serialization works fine when I change the List type in my RequestPayload to LossIncurredPayload, but if I did this then I would have to have a specific RequestPayload class for each type, this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XmlIncludeAttribute` on `RequestPayload` class. Specify it for all derived types.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(LossIncurredPayload))]
public class RequestPayload
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Payload> BOM_Request { get; set; }
}
```